# XML Soap request with no header credentials

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, request

So I know that there are a lot of questions about this, but every question works with headers.
I have a SOAP request without a header:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v2="https://www.onderdelenlijn.nl/services/cars/v2.asmx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v2:airbags_get>
         <v2:credentials>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v2:username>admin</v2:username>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v2:password>adminpass</v2:password>
         </v2:credentials>
      </v2:airbags_get>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to use the following code to authenticate via the body:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('https://www.onderdelenlijn.nl/services/cars/v2.asmx?wsdl');

$soapmessage = [
        'credentials' => [
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'adminpass'
        ]
];

$result = $client->airbags_get($soapmessage);
print_r($result);
?>
```

To be clear: normal SOAP requests need to be authenticated in the header, i dont have one?

> Error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding:
>   object has no 'parameters' propert

y

Comment: Any specific error? PHP + SOAP is often a nightmare, if you don't find a solution I would recommend checking out nusoap, it's saved me a lot of problems in the past.

Comment: @BrettGregson i edited the question to include the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the expected `parameters` value in your soap message:

```
$soapmessage = [
  'credentials' => [
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'adminpass'
  ],
  // Add this
  'parameters'  =>  [ 
    'culture'  =>  'en',
    'airbagid' =>  1,
  ],
];
```

If you view the soap [URL](https://www.onderdelenlijn.nl/services/cars/v2.asmx?op=airbags_get) you can see the sample request:

```
<soap:Body>
  <airbags_get xmlns="https://www.onderdelenlijn.nl/services/cars/v2.asmx">
    <credentials>
      <username>string</username>
      <password>string</password>
    </credentials>
    <parameters>
      <culture>nl or en or de or fr or es or pl</culture>
      <airbagid>int</airbagid>
    </parameters>
  </airbags_get>
</soap:Body>
```

So your full code will be something like:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://www.onderdelenlijn.nl/services/cars/v2.asmx?wsdl');
$soapmessage = [
  'credentials' => [
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'adminpass'
  ],
  'parameters'  =>  [
    'culture' =>  'en',
    'airbagid' =>  1,
  ],
];

$result = $client->airbags_get($soapmessage);
print_r($result);
```